RabbitMQ entrypoint not executed properly
I am using the MQTT protocol and I am using a custom entrypoint script which enables the plugin and then also enables the corresponding feature flags. My Dockerfile looks like that
FROM rabbitmq:3.13-management-alpine AS custom-rabbitmq

# Copy the entrypoint script into the container
COPY deployments/custom/rabbitmq/scripts/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Set the entrypoint to the custom script
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]


and my entrypoint looks like
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e # fail script if update fails

ENABLE_MQTT=${ENABLE_MQTT:-false}

echo whoami: "$(whoami)"
echo RabbitMQ dir contents before detached run: "$(ls -la /var/lib/rabbitmq/)"

if [ "$ENABLE_MQTT" = "true" ]; then
  echo "Enabling MQTT plugin before starting server..."
  rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_mqtt

  if ! grep -q rabbitmq_mqtt /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins; then
    echo "Failed to enable the MQTT plugin. Exiting..."
    exit 1
  fi
fi

env
ls -al /usr/local/bin/
cat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh rabbitmq-server -detached

echo RabbitMQ dir contents before detached run: "$(ls -la /var/lib/rabbitmq/)"

RABBITMQ_PROCESS_ID_FILE=/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@"$(hostname)".pid
rabbitmqctl wait --timeout 60 "$RABBITMQ_PROCESS_ID_FILE"

if [ "$ENABLE_MQTT" = "true" ]; then
  # Enable the MQTT related feature flags
  echo "Enabling MQTT feature flags..."
  rabbitmqctl enable_feature_flag delete_ra_cluster_mqtt_node
  rabbitmqctl enable_feature_flag mqtt_v5
  rabbitmqctl enable_feature_flag rabbit_mqtt_qos0_queue
else
  echo "MQTT not enabled. Continuing with normal startup..."
fi

exec rabbitmq-server

I am building the image using
 docker build -f deployments/custom/rabbitmq/docker/dev.dockerfile -t mqtt-rabbit .

My problem is that the entrypoint timesout at
rabbitmqctl wait --timeout 60 "$RABBITMQ_PROCESS_ID_FILE"

The logs are
Waiting for pid file '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@74c4817affea.pid' to appear
Error: operation wait on node rabbit@74c4817affea timed out. Timeout value used: 60000

This command
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh rabbitmq-server -detached

should have created the pid file.
If I manually override the entrypoint
docker run -it --rm -e ENABLE_MQTT=true mqtt-rabbit bash

and run the commands interactively, one by one, it all works.
As you can see from the script I have added all sorts of ls, echo and env commands to debug this but the environment looks identical so far.
The issue is that the docker-entrypoint.sh does not execute if invoked from the entrypoint.sh. It does not produce any error but when the wait command searches for the process ID file it cannot find it.
I run the same commands interactively and RabbitMQ successfully starts.
